# How to retrieve specific value from Database(mysql) with php

Tags: php, mysql, image

Here I am displaying 4 images on my page from database.

Table `equipments` with columns:

```
equi_id, equi_name, equi_type, equi_descp, equi_img
```

Markup:

```
<!--Content-->
<center><b><u><font size="6em">Our Equipments</font></center></b></u>
<div class="container" id="content-img">
    <div class = "row" id="img-div" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#content-modal">
        <?php
            include("database.php");
            $q="select * from equipments WHERE eq_type = 'chest'";
            $result=mysql_query($q,$con);
            while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "<div  class='col-md-6' id='".$res['equi_name']."'<span id='equip_head'><b><center>".$res['equi_name']."</center></b></span> <br /> <img src='".$res['equi_img']."' class='img-responsive'></div>";
                }
        ?>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the description (`equi_descp`) from the same table when clicking on any image. This code is bootstrap enabled.

```
<!--Content Pop-Up-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="content-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <?php
                    include("database.php");
                    $q="select * from equipments WHERE eq_type = 'chest'";
                    $result=mysql_query($q,$con);
                    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo "<h4 class='modal-title'>".$res['equi_name']."</h4>";
                    }

                    echo "</div>";
                ?>
                <?php
                    include("database.php");
                    $q="select * from equipments WHERE eq_type = 'chest'";
                    $result=mysql_query($q,$con);
                    echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
                    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo "<p>'".$res['equi_descp']."'</p>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With my code, click on any image returns the description of all the images not just the one that is clicked on.

How can I fix my code to only display the description of the image that is clicked on?

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because you are showing all chests no?

Comment: First of all, use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Second you are including the database file twice (you only need to include it once, in the top of your file. use `include_once`. Third you execute the same query twice, so find a smart way to bundle it and still output the way you want it.

Comment: yes i am showing all chest. 
and that is my doubt here. I want the proper condition that will retrieve the name and description accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `WHERE` part of the query in your popup to target the specific item you wish to access. For example, as `WHERE equi_id = 5`. You obviously need to add the ID to the URL of the popup window. (How exactly, it depends on how you create your popups; your code doesn't demonstrate that.)

Don't forget to properly sanitize the ID variable from the URL before you stick it into your query. Also, you may want to switch to using `mysqli_` in place of the deprecated `mysql_` database driver.